# Rails: devise Tut

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I tried this: http://blog.blazingcloud.net/2011/01/08/devise-authentication-in-rails-3/

Where to add the dependencies as shown?

//sorry, I changed my question, after you answered! Sorry for this.

Comment: dude please don't edit your question and change the context of the answer completly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bundler is mainly to manage your gem dependencies. so when you add devise to your Gemfile and run bundle install, it installs its run time dependencies as well. devise gem depends upon bcrypt-ruby,warden. [This](https://rubygems.org/gems/devise) link provides you details about the dependencies of devise gem.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to set up any of them. That will happen automatically for you once you add devise.

Comment: I run rails g devise:views. I want to integrate the views in the layout/application. What is to do?

Comment: There's a good Railscast about devise in here: http://railscasts.com/episodes/209-introducing-devise?autoplay=true